# Using law of logic, simplify the statement form $A \lor [\neg(\neg A)\land B]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Simplifying the given expression led me to $A\lor\neg B$. Here is what I did:

$A \lor [\neg(\neg A)\land B]$ -------> Given

$A \lor [\neg(\neg A)\lor \neg B]$ ------> De Morgan's Law

$A \lor (A\lor \neg B)$ -----------> Law of double negation

$(A \lor A)\lor \neg B$ -----------> Associative Law

$A \lor \neg B$-----------------> Idempotent Law

Now, I want to know if my application of De Morgan's Law (second step) is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: You may also rewrite the last statement as $B\to A$ (but maybe you want to keep it with $\land,\lor,\lnot$ only)

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formulas. eg the $\vee$ symbol is \vee, the $\neg$ symbol is \neg and the $\wedge$ is \wedge. All you have to do is to surround your formula, e.g A \vee \neg B, with dollar symbols and voilà. : $A \vee \neg B$ :)

Comment: @OlivierRoche I use `\land` (logic and) for $\land$ and `\lor` (logic or) for $\lor$. Easier to remember for me.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Nice, I wasn't aware of these aliases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, but you may simplify even further : by definition of $\to$, the last line is equivalent to $$B \to A$$

Comment: Oh my! You're right! I just proved their logical equivalence through truth table! Thanks a lot!